# Drupal 6 Form Api adding an item to an existing form

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-fapi

I want to add a new item into an existing form. I have the ID of the form and I know I need to use hook form_alter but not sure how to add it.

```
function modulename_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
    switch ($form_id) {
        case 'form id goes here':
            // Need to do something here....         
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `&$form` variable is a reference, whatever you do to it changes the original value.  so just add it to `$form;`

```
//After, need to do something here:
$form['my_new_field'] = array(

 '#type' => 'select',
 //etc..

 );


//You can also add a new validation here:

$form['#validate'][]  = 'my_valiation_callback';
```

See the [drupal api ref for better details:](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter/6)